# Specifying initial vector for finding Eigenvectors using Arnoldi method

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am trying to speedup the calculation of eigenvalues, given that I have good guesses for the eigenvectors. From what I know of Arnoldi/Lanczos, my good guesses should be helpful.  Unfortunately, I am unable to see any speedup when I give these guesses to Mathematica.

Here is a simple and very artificial example.

I first create a random vector:

```
testvec = SparseArray[Table[RandomInteger[2000] -> Random[], {500}],{2000}]
```

I then create a matrix for which this is an eigenvector:

```
testmat = KroneckerProduct[testvec, testvec]
```

By construction the eigenvalue is

```
ev=(testvec.testmat.testvec)/(testvec.testvec)
```

On my computer (a macbook air running Mathematica 10), the following takes about 0.24 seconds:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Eigenvalues[testmat, 1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]]
```

Indeed it finds the right eigenvalue.  I now feed it information about the eigenvector:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Eigenvalues[testmat, 1,Method -> {"Arnoldi", "StartingVector" -> testvec}]]
```

This once again takes 0.24 seconds.

1. Why does this not give me a speedup?
2. What can I do differently to get a speedup?

Note:  I realize that I can get about a factor of 4 speedup by using the "Shift" option -- but it seems I should be able to get a couple orders of magnitude better by using a good starting vector.

Comment: In playing around with your problem, I was unable to select a badstartvec that would make it worse either. Various randomizations, or all zeros except for a random "1"...result seems to be independent of the "StartingVector". Got the same eigenvalue and same timing (percentage points) no matter what.

Answer (score 5):

Since the test matrix you use has rank 1, many iterative schemes will converge very rapidly.  Starting with a more general real symmetric, positive-definite matrix, we compare 3 ways of computing the largest eigenvalue (and corresponding eigenvector)

```
a = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {2000, 2000}];
testmat = Transpose[a].a;
```

A generic approach

```
AbsoluteTiming[{val, vec} = Eigensystem[testmat, 1];]
(* {0.893087, Null} *)
```

The uninitialised Arnoldi method is 5 x faster

```
AbsoluteTiming[{val1, vec1} = 
   Eigensystem[testmat, 1, Method -> "Arnoldi"];]
(* {0.162465, Null} *)
```

The initialised Arnoldi method is almost 4 x faster again

```
AbsoluteTiming[{val2, vec2} = 
   Eigensystem[testmat, 1, 
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", "StartingVector" -> First[vec]}];]
(* {0.046821, Null} *)
```

All give the same eigenvalue

```
Flatten[{val, val1, val2}]
(* {7935.59, 7935.59, 7935.59} *)
```

EDIT

I also note that your examples evaluate much faster if converted to full, rather than sparse  arrays.

Comment: In an actual application that will necessitate the use of Arnoldi, converting to a dense array will likely be prohibitive in memory.